# Can't get AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to display

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avfoundation

I'm trying to get the feed from the ios device's camera to display on screen and I don't want to use the ImagePickerController because I want to have more control over the look of the view on screen and I want to have more control over the camera's aperture and sample rate.

Here's the code I'm using in my UIViewController's viewDidLoad method:

```
//Setting up the camera
AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
//This gets the back camera, which is the default video avcapturedevice
AVCaptureDevice *camera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *cameraInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:camera error:&error];
if (cameraInput) {
    [captureSession addInput:cameraInput];
}
else {
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camera not found" message:@"Your device must have a camera in order to use this feature" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];
UIView* cameraView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
previewLayer.frame = cameraView.bounds; 
previewLayer.videoGravity = @"AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect";
[cameraView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
[self.view addSubview:cameraView];
```

Yet nothing appears on the screen when the view loads, and I don't get an error message.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never actually start the capture session in the code that you have shown:

```
[captureSession startRunning];
```

---

Also, I would recommend that you look at [the AVCam sample code that Apple has provided](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/AVCam_AAPLCameraViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-AVCam_AAPLCameraViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6) to see how they setup their capture session and preview layer. It contains some good tips regarding how to manage your capture session (they dispatch everything to a custom serial queue). For example, it contains these comments in the code:

```
// In general it is not safe to mutate an AVCaptureSession or any of its inputs, outputs, or connections from multiple threads at the same time.
// Why not do all of this on the main queue?
// -[AVCaptureSession startRunning] is a blocking call which can take a long time. We dispatch session setup to the sessionQueue so that the main queue isn't blocked (which keeps the UI responsive).
```